# Read the discriminator column value before the flush. How?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to read my mapped discriminator column before the flush.

I have this discriminator column mapped in the `Child1` entity:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = Child1.TYPE)
class Child1 extends Father {

    TYPE = "Child1Type";

}
```

And the super class `Father`:

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = Father.TYPE_COLUMN)
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
abstract class Father {

    TYPE_COLUMN = "type"

    @Column(name = "type", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String type;

}
```

If I call the method in the `Father` to verify the type, I receive a NullPointerException in the `type` variable:

```
public boolean isChild1() {
    return this.type.equals(Child1.TYPE);
}
```

Because I didn't save (and flush) the entity in the database. Is there something to do in this case?

Comment: That's a very convoluted way of verifying the type. Why not simply `this instanceof Child1` or `isChild1()` implemented in `Parent` to return `false` and overridden in `Child1` to return `true`? Also, how come you don't know the concrete type of an entity *before* flushing?

Comment: @crizzis well, you are right. I'm trying to read the value (because the code is already implemented), but your suggestion resolve and it's more simple. You can post this as answer, I will accept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really *need* to read the value of the discriminator to determine the concrete type of the entity. There are far easier solutions:

- Using `instanceof` (`this instanceof Child1`)
- Implementing `isChild1` in `Parent` to return `false` and overriding it to return `true` in `Child1` (which is more OOP)

Even if you retrieve the entities later on, JPA will use the discriminator column to determine the concrete type and instantiate it. Why not take advantage of that?